# Azure Cosmos DB - Gremlin latitude longitude format conversion issues

Tags: geocoding, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am trying to convert airport **GeoCoordinate** data i.e. [**IATA Code**, **latitude**, **longitude**] to **Gremlin** **Vertex** in an **Azure Cosmos DB Graph API** project.
**Vertex** conversion is mainly done through an **Asp.Net Core 2.0 console application** using **CSVReader** to stream and convert data from a **airport.dat** (csv) file. 
This process involves converting over 6,000 lines...

So for example, in original **airport.dat** source file, the **Montreal Pierre Elliott Trudeau International Airport** would be listed using a similar model as below:

```
1,"Montreal / Pierre Elliott Trudeau International Airport","Montreal","Canada","YUL","CYUL",45.4706001282,-73.7407989502,118,-5,"A","America/Toronto","airport","OurAirports"
```

Then if I define a **Gremlin** **Vertex** creation query in my cod as followed:

```
var gremlinQuery = $"g.addV('airport').property('id', \"{code}\").property('latitude', {lat}).property('longitude', {lng})";
```

then when the console application is launched, the **Vertex** conversion process would be generated successfully in exact similar fashion:

```
1 g.addV('airport').property('id', "YUL").property('latitude', 45.4706001282).property('longitude', -73.7407989502)
```

Note that in the case of **Montreal Airport** (which is located in N.A not in the Far East...), the **longitude** is properly formatted with **minus** (**-**) **prefix**, though this seems to be lost underway when doing a query on Azure Portal.

```
{
"id": "YUL",
"label": "airport",
"type": "vertex",
"properties": {
  "latitude": [
    {
      "id": "13a30a4f-42cc-4413-b201-11efe7fa4dbb",
      "value": 45.4706001282
    }
  ],
  "longitude": [
    {
      "id": "74554911-07e5-4766-935a-571eedc21ca3",
      "value": 73.7407989502 <---- //Should be displayed as -73.7407989502
    }
  ]
}
```

This is a bit awkward. If anyone has encountered a similar issue and was able to fix it, then I'm fully open to suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestion, though problem has now been solved in my case. 
What was previously suggested as a working answer scenario [and voted 1...] has long been settled in case of **.Net 4.5.2** [& .**Net 4.6.1**] version used in combination with **Microsoft.Azure.Graph 0.2.4 -preview**. The issue of my question didn't really concern that and may have been a bit more subtle... Perhaps I should have put a bit more emphasis on the fact that the issue was mainly related to **Microsoft.Azure.Graph 0.3.1 -preview** used in **Core 2.0** + **dotnet CLI** scenario.

According to following Graph - **Multiple issues with parsing of numeric constants in the graph gremlin query #438** comments on **Github**,

https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/438

there are indeed some fair reasons to believe that the issue was a bug with **Microsoft.Azure.Graph 0.3.1 -preview**. I chose to use **Gremlin.Net** approach instead and managed to get the proper result I expected.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I just executed Gremlin query on my side and I could retrieve the inserted Vertex as follows:

[image]

Then, I just queried on Azure Portal and retrieved the record as follows:

[image]

Per my understanding, you need to check the execution of your code and verify the response of your query to narrow down this issue.